# Ring-segment overlapping

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

*How can I find if a 2D-segment overlaps (pure overlap, not abutting or touching) with a 2D-ring (convex)?*

My first approaches were to use:

1. [disjoint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/disjoint.html) But it did not work because touching/abutting are not not considered disjoint
2. [overlaps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/overlaps.html) But it did not work because touching/abutting are considered as overlaps

I tried several other combinations (using [within](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_3_with_strategy.html) for example) and I can't find an easy way. By easy I mean: use a couple of boost-geometry algorithms without implementing a computational geometry algorithm.

I believe the solution is somewhere in the strategies...

I guess I can redefine the problem: *How do I find abutting rings (polygons)?*
(note: I can create a degenerate ring from edge).

Here is a figure of what I want. Red segment should return **OVERLAP**, blue **NO OVERLAP**.

[image]

**System: Boost_1.54, CentOS-5, gcc-4.7.2**

Comment: Boost.Geometry implements spatial relations defined by DE9IM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM). I'm not sure what exactly is the problem you're faceing. Is the Crosses spatial relation you need? I'm confused because overlaps() shouldn't work for a Segment(1d) and Ring(2d), touching Polygons/Rings can be found using touches().

Comment: @AdamWulkiewicz: I solved some issues e.g. that to use `touches()` both rings need have their points with the same order i.e. CW or CCW but the problem is that I want to find if a **2d-segment** touches a **2d-ring** and `touches()` does not work for segment-ring. I tried to create a degenerate ring with the edge points: (edge.first, edge.second, edge.first) but it does not always work.

`overlaps()` is not appropriate because I want only touching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently (1.55) touches() isn't implemented for Segment/Ring. We plan to release more variants in 1.56, probably not Segment/Ring but you should be able to use Linestring/Ring. You could test it using the development version of the library:

http://github.com/boostorg/geometry/tree/develop

Also the issue with CCW Polygons in touches() is fixed in the develop branch.